# Mix colors of overlapping shapes in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, colors, animation

I'm sure this is trivial, but I cannot find how to do this.

I have two shapes that are animated to overlap. One shape is yellow, the other one is blue. I'd like the color of the overlapping parts to be green.

I tried setting both shapes to 50% transparent, but while that makes them less opaque, it does not make them green.

Is there a way to color only the overlapping parts of two animated shapes?

I get this as the output with yellow at 16% transparency:
[image]

Is there a way to explicitly specify the overlap color?

Comment: Setting transparency on the top shape should work as expected - what are you seeing instead?  What version of PPT are you using?

Comment: @AC Thanks, when changing the colors to hard blue and hard yellow, I do see the overlapping parts as green. Just chose the wrong colors I guess.